# append static elements in object to each object in array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, ecmascript-6

How do I take this object and array.

```
const data = {
    type: "hello",
    point: 1.8
};

const raw = [
    {
        x: [1, 2],
        y: [-1.1, -1.2]
    },
    {
        x: [14, 24],
        y: [-1.14, 1.24]
    }
];
```

Then "append" the items in the `data` object to each object in the `raw` array. The desired end result is;

```
const result = [
    {
        x: [1, 2],
        y: [-1.1, -1.2],
        type: "hello",
        point: 1.8
    },
    {
        x: [14, 24],
        y: [-1.14, 1.24],
        type: "hello",
        point: 1.8
    }
];
```

I tried using `map` but this object works with arrays, then I looked at using `Object.keys` but am having no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` with spreading:

```js
const data = {type:"hello",point:1.8};
const raw = [{x:[1,2],y:[-1.1,-1.2]},{x:[14,24],y:[-1.14,1.24]}];
const result = raw.map(e => ({ ...e, ...data }));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var data = {type:"hello",point:1.8};
var raw = [{x:[1,2],y:[-1.1,-1.2]},{x:[14,24],y:[-1.14,1.24]}];
var result = raw.map(function(e) { 
  return Object.assign({}, e, data);
});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: I see, using Object.assign is the older ES5 syntax. But the same can be achieve using ES6 spread syntax. Lovely thank you. I have marked this as the official solution.

Comment: @Sigex - See my comments on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is indeed the tool you want. I'd probably combine it with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the `map` callback parameter list and property spread in the result value:

```
const result = raw.map(({x, y}) => ({x, y, ...data}));
```

Live Copy:

```js
const data = {
    type: "hello",
    point: 1.8
};
const raw = [
    {
        x: [1, 2],
        y: [-1.1, -1.2]
    },
    {
        x: [14, 24],
        y: [-1.14, 1.24]
    }
];
const result = raw.map(({x, y}) => ({x, y, ...data}));
console.log(result);
```

Note that if `data` had any properties whose values were *objects* (`data` in your example doesn't), using spread will copy only the references to the objects, it won't make deep copies. So all of your `result` objects should share them. You could [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) if that were relevant.

Comment: Thank you, I prefer the use of the spread operator on each object in the raw array. Rather than destructing and referencing objects x and y directly. The actual code I have has about 6 objects. I limited it to just x and y for the sample.

Comment: @Sigex - Yeah. As I mentioned in a comment on Jack's answer, it's not clear to me why I limited it to `x` and `y`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution;

```js
const data = {type:"hello",point:1.8};
const raw = [{x:[1,2],y:[-1.1,-1.2]},{x:[14,24],y:[-1.14,1.24]}];
const result = raw.map(r => Object.assign(r, data));
console.log(result);
```

Some feedback on this approach would be appreciated. Looking a the solutions provided now. Thank you all.

Comment: That works just fine. The only significant difference between this and what Jack and I did is that you're **modifying** the objects in the `raw` array, and we're making shallow copies of them. So `raw` and `result` will both contain the same, extended, objects (`raw[0].point` will be `1.8`). With Jack's and my approach, `raw` would have the original objects unchanged, and `result` would have new objects with `x`, `y`, and the new properties.

Comment: One other minor thing is that property spread notation is quite new (ES2018). If you want the equivalent of Jack's answer using `Object.assign` instead, it would be: `=> Object.assign({}, e, data)`.

Comment: Thank you T.J, I am using Typescript so spread operator is fine. But helpful to those who read this and are using JavaScript ES5.